# batch file goto next xcopy command if windows "Admin" username has changed

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to be able to run just one instance of xcopy rather than many, from a usb drive to .\admin\desktop on the computer I have plugged it in, however there might be some computers I get on that have the admin username changed to the name of the person.  Is there a generic batch namimg convention for the admin user account for windows?  If so I'd like to just use that whatever it may be instead of listing everyone's username for every computer and guessing what it might be without looking everytime.
Here is what I have so far, it works well if I know for a fact that the "Admin" user is still labeled "Admin."

```
@echo off

xcopy "%~dp0M1k_SWPCB\*.*" "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\SWPCB\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y

pause
```

I tried 'All Users' as well, but in some cases the directory doesn't exist and it will not work.  Plus if the computer has multiple users I don't want it on everyones' desktop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All users have a SID identifier and the local admin account always ends with the -500 suffix, so you can get the Admin username by checking the SID's on the Registry:

```
@Echo OFF

FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%@ IN ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" ^| FIND "-500"') DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('Reg Query "%%@" /v "ProfileImagePath" ^| FIND /V "%%@"') DO (
        Echo    Admin SID: %%~n@
        Echo Admin Folder: %%B
    )
)

Pause>NUL&Exit
```

**Output:**

```
   Admin SID: S-1-5-21-148789306-3749789949-2179752015-500
Admin Folder: C:\Users\Administrador
```

Another way to do it is with an VBScript, you can use it in your Batch file and write the Admin name to a textfile, then next you will set a variable with the content of the textfile. (I don't wrote this function):

```
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")
objComputerName = objNetwork.ComputerName

Set objwmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" & objComputerName)
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Account where Domain = '" & cstr(objComputerName) & "'"

For Each Admin In objwmi.ExecQuery(qry)
    If (Left(Admin.sid, 6) = "S-1-5-" And Right(Admin.sid,4) = "-500") Then MsgBox Admin.name)
Next
```

PS: Maybe someone will post other solution saying that listing the group names is another choice... but groupnames is not a generic solution 'cause the native language.

Comment: Thanks for the post.  Wouldn't I then be able to replace my code "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin" with %%B?  I tried it and the output Admin folder for this computer is C:\Users\administrator, but for some reason it doesn't work the same.  Instead of C:\ it created a %B folder on my usb flash drive(where my batch is located).  So when I place the %%B and echo the xcopy I get: <pre>  <code> xcopy "E:\M1k_SWPCB\*.*" "%B\Desktop\SWPCB\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y

Comment: Here is what I tried:  <pre> <code>    @Echo OFF

    FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%@ IN ('Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" ^| FIND "-500"') DO (
    FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('Reg Query "%%@" /v "ProfileImagePath" ^| FIND /V "%%@"') DO (
        Echo    Admin SID: %%~n@
        Echo Admin Folder: %%B
    )
)

xcopy "%~dp0M1k_SWPCB\*.*" "%%B\Desktop\SWPCB\" /d /s /h /v /c /f /k /y

Pause>NUL&Exit

Comment: Ok, I just set drive to equal %%B inside the DO() and put %drive% in my code and it worked.  Thanks so much for your post.  Have a good week.

Comment: You are using the For variable "%%B" outside the For loop that's the reason why don't worked, solution is what you've found, setting the %%B to a variable or use "Xcopy + %%B" INSIDE the for loop. regards!